# jQuery Show / Hide affects sibling select box functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed two select boxes - one that controls the visibility of the other.
**On page load** the ***controlled*** select box `(#select02)` functions exactly as I would like, as long as I do not show / hide the select box in question `(#select02)`, by selecting options in the ***controlling*** select box `(select01)`.

Once I do that - all functionality in the ***controlled*** select box `(#select02)` ceases to function.

So my Question is - How do I maintain the functionality of the ***"controlled"*** select box `(#select02)`, **after** showing/hiding it?

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/collyg/4f193nsr/4/)

For those of you who prefer the obligatory live code....
The HTML:

```
<div>
<h1>The controlling box</h1>
<p>(play with this second)</p>
    <select id = "select01" size = 2>
        <option value="value01">Hide Other Div</option>
        <option value="value02">Show Other Div</option>
    </select>
</div><!--end section-->

<div id = "slide">
<h1>The controlled box</h1>
<p>(play with this first)</p>
    <select size = "4" id = "select02" class = "moduleSelect" multiple>
        <option class = "module 30" value = "2">OptionA</option>
        <option class = "module 30" value = "2">OptionB</option>
        <option class = "module 15" value = "1">OptionC</option>
        <option class = "module 15" value = "1">OptionD</option>
    </select>

<div id = "hidden">
    <b><i class = "hiddenHeader">You have chosen:</i><p id = "userChoice"></p></b>
    <b><i class = "hiddenHeader">This Total:</i><p id = "Tot"></p></b>
     <p id = "Status"></p>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="remove" class = "remove"><p>RESELECT</p></a>
</div><!--END #HIDDEN01-->
</div><!--END #SLIDE-->
```

The Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//TURN OFF ALL SELECTIONS IN THE OPTIONS (NO ISSUE IT SEEMS)
$("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$(".moduleSelect").prop("disabled", false);  
$(".module").prop("disabled", false); 

//DECLARE THE SELECT TOTAL VARIABLE
var Total = 0;

//THE HIDE FUNCTIONALITY EXECUTED BY THE "CONTROLLING" SELECT BOX 
//(OSTENSIBLY THE ISSUE, IT SEEMS)

if($('#select01').val() == 'value01'){
    $('#slide').slideUp('slow', 'swing');
}

$('#select01').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'value02'){
        $('#slide').slideDown('slow', 'swing');
        return true;
    }
    $('#slide').slideUp('slow', 'swing');
});

//THE USER FEEDBACK FUNTIONALITY PROVIDED BY THE "CONTROLLED" SELECT BOX 
//(NO ISSUE, IT SEEMS)

    //WHEN A USER CLICKS ON ANY OPTION
    $("#select02").change(function(){

        //TOGGLE MULTIPLE SELECTION
         $("#select02 option").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        });

         if (Total <30){

                    if ($("option:selected").val() == "0"){
                        Total += 0;
                    }
                    else if ($("option:selected").val() == "1"){
                        Total += 15;
                    }
                    else if ($("option:selected").val() == "2"){
                        Total += 30;
                    }
                    else if ($("option:selected").val() == ""){
                        Total = 0;
                    }

                    if (Total == 30){
                        $(this).prop("disabled", true);  
                        $("#Tot").text(Total);
                        $("#Status").html("<i>(You have selected the maximum required number of  Credits)</i>");
                        $("#hidden").css('display', 'block');
                        $("#userChoice").append("<li>" + $("option:selected", this).text() + "</li>");
                    }

                    if (Total == 15){
                        $(this).children(".30").prop("disabled", true);
                        $("#Tot").text(Total);
                        $("#Status").text("Select another 15 credits");
                        $("#hidden").css('display', 'block');
                        $("#userChoice").append("<li>" + $("option:selected", this).text() + "</li>");
                    }

            }else{
                $("#Status").text("You have already selected the required number of  Credits");
            }
        });

// THE RESELECT FUNCTION TO CLEAR 
//(NO ISSUE, IT SEEMS)

    $("div a#remove").click(function () {     
        $("#select02 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        $("#select02").prop("disabled", false);  
        $("#select02").children(".30").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#hidden").css('display', 'none');
        $("#userChoice").empty();
        $("#Tot").empty();
        $("#Status").empty();
    Total = 0;
    });     
});
```

Please bear in mind that I am self taught web developer, a total noob, and probably doing something fundamentally WRONG! :) Also please excuse my insultingly bad programming.....

Thanking those enthusiastic problem solvers amongst you in advance.
CollyG

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "null and void" but fiddle seems to work for me on FF

Comment: OK @artm that text is edited. Have you read my question properly? Because it DOES NOT work in any browser.

Comment: FYI you can include runnable code right in your question using the "Code Snippet" button on the editor.

Comment: `$('#slide').slideDown('slow', 'swing').removeAttr("disabled");`

Comment: `if (Total == 30){ $(this).prop("disabled", true);` you're disabling it yourself.

Comment: Neither of your answers address the core issue @artm - the "this" to which you refer, refers to the select options within the controlled select box, and not the select box itself, or the associated jQuery functionality. Please re-read my question again before answering.

Comment: @collyg Ok, good luck.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak and @artm for your feedback. It is appreciated. Salman has provided an interesting solution below, and I suggest a few upvotes. Apparently _.show() / .hide()_ has little to do with it, but "**jQuery .value()**" was at the root of the issue. Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4f193nsr/5/). Basically, there is a problem in the following code:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("option:selected").val();
});
```

This code grabs the value of the first selected option **in the document**. Which explains why the code for second select does not work when you select something from the first select.

---

Having said that, a better solution is to recalculate the totals when the user selects or de-select options. Use [`jQuery.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val) which returns an array of selected options. So we have:

```
$("#select02").change(function() {
    var Total = 0;
    $.each($(this).val(), function(_, value) {
        if (value === "1") {
            Total += 15;
        } else if (value === "2") {
            Total += 30;
        }
    });
});
```

Once you have the total you can update the display.

Comment: Thank you Salman, your help is very much appreciated. Quite obviously I was approaching the problem incorrectly, and also unaware of the of the array return from "jQuery .val()". If I had the ability I would upvote. Alas I cannot. Many thanks again!